# Short ascending textbox number lines array order

Tags: vb.net

I have Textbox Lines:

For example:

```
Lines1: 41,27,44,54
Lines2: 51,41,44,54
Lines3: 71,27,44,54
```

It should display:

Expected Output:

```
27,41,44,54
41,44,51,54
27,44,54,71
```

This is a code that doesn't work with "," it practically doesn't show me the values ​​displayed by the comma. basically shows me: 27414454 and so on...

```
Dim b = String.Join(",", str.Split(",").Select(Function(x) Integer.Parse(x.Trim())).OrderBy(Function(x) x))
```

this is a code that arranges only the lines.

```
        Dim textLines As List(Of String) = New List(Of String)
        textLines = TextBox2.Lines.ToList()
        textLines.Sort()
```

Comment: I just tested your first code snippet with `str` equal to `"41,27,44,54"` and `b` was equal to `"27,41,44,54"`, so apparently you don't even know what issue you need help with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to split each line to get arrays to sort, then join the arrays back to get the lines.

Here's a one liner example:

```vb
txtOutput.Lines = txtInput.Lines.
    Select(Function(x) x.Split({","c}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).
    OrderBy(Function(y) Integer.Parse(y))).
    Select(Function(z) String.Join(",", z)).ToArray
```

The `txtInput` contains:

```
41,27,44,54
51,41,44,54
71,27,44,54
```

The `txtOutput` displays:

```
27,41,44,54
41,44,51,54
27,44,54,71
```